# How do you change a class dynamically on scrolling to a specific element in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, event-handling

I can do this easily with onMouseWheel, but it doesn't work for users who are scrolling with the keyboard (arrow keys).
This is a demo of the functionality I want using onMouseWheel.

```
    <h2  [ngClass]="{ 'scrolled-into-view' : scrolled }"  (wheel)="onMouseWheel($event)">
      This text should turn red when scrolled into view.
    </h2>
```

```
  scrolled = false;
  onMouseWheel(evt) {
    this.scrolled = true;
  }
```

https://angular-ivy-5hgjb5.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the HostListener decorator to handle the scroll event. From there I compared the window.scroll to offsetTop of the element I want scrolled into view.

Here's the component JS:

```
import { Component, HostListener, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  flag = false;
  @ViewChild("scrolledToElement", { static: false })
  scrolledToElement: ElementRef;
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
  onScroll(event) {
    if (window.scrollY > this.scrolledToElement.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
      this.flag = true;
      console.log("flag", this.flag);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blue">
    When you scroll to the div below, it should turn from red to green.
</div>
<div #scrolledToElement class="second-block" [ngClass]="flag ? 'red' : 'green' "></div>
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhb4yw?file=src/app/app.component.html